# Form Tag Helpers Cannot Process '-' in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, attributes, form-helpers, parsley

I am trying to use Parsley for Rails 4 with Form Tag Helpers.

As said in the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_area_tag)

"Options" provide a way for custom attributes; However, Parsley uses the notation "data-parsley". Rails cannot interpret the "-" and application brings out an error.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to write `data` tags in Rails (or other tags with `-`):

```
data: {parsley: 'something'} # -> data-parsley="something"
```

or

```
'data-parsley' => 'something' # -> data-parsley="something"
```

Also, there is a strange, but useful behavior: inside `data` braces, you can use `_` and it will renders as `-`, for ex:

```
data: {customer_id: 'id'} # -> data-customer-id="id"
```

The same, as

```
data: {customer: {id: 'id'}} # -> data-customer-id="id"
```